# Best SQL syntax to get children items

Tags: mysql, join

I am creating a blog system and I wants to get the post comments. The comments has a multilevel tree, but I am using only one table to save all.

Do you know a best syntax to get 5 comments and your children comments (replies)?

And if I need to limit the number of replies to 5, for example, how I can do it in just one query?

This is a print of my table: **blog_comments**
[image]

Comment: The table name is **blog_comments**.

Comment: What have you tried? (Oh, and edit your question rather than posting corrections as comments, please)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried `SELECT *
FROM blog_comments
JOIN blog_comments ON blog_comments.parent = blog_comments.id
WHERE blog_comments.post_id = 1;` and I having the error `Error in query (1066): Not unique table/alias: 'blog_comments' `.

Answer (score 2):

Use a self-join on the `blog_comments` table.  This query will give the 5 most recent blog posts along with all their children of one descendant deep.

```
SELECT t1.id AS parentID, t2.id AS childID, t1.content AS parentContent,
    t2.content AS childContent
FROM
(
    SELECT id, content
    FROM blog_comments
    ORDER BY creation_date DESC
    LIMIT 5
) t1
INNER JOIN blog_comments t2
    ON t1.id = t2.parent
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id
```

**Update:**

I much rather prefer the following query, which shows the five most recent blog posts, each on its own row, followed by all children replies.  This more closely resembles what you would want to display in your app layer.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t.childId = -1 THEN 'parent' ELSE 'child' END AS type,
    t.content
FROM
(
    SELECT childId, parentId, content FROM
    (
        SELECT -1 AS childId, id AS parentId, content AS content
        FROM blog_comments
        WHERE parent IS NULL
        ORDER BY creation_date DESC
        LIMIT 5
    ) t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.id AS childId, t1.parent AS parentId, t1.content AS content
    FROM blog_comments t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM blog_comments
        WHERE parent IS NULL
        ORDER BY creation_date DESC
        LIMIT 5
    ) t2
        ON t1.parent = t2.id
) t
ORDER BY t.parentId, t.childId
```

Here is a link to a running demo:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Very thanks! You are a master [Tim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen).